# $cordovaFileTransfer can not work

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

use $cordovaFileTransfer to upload images,but it stop at 99%, $_FILES is empty in PHP;
and i get evt object.

```
{"bubbles":"false","cancelBubble":"false","cancelable":"false","lengthComputable":"true","loaded":"16656","total":"491176"}
{"bubbles":"false","cancelBubble":"false","cancelable":"false","lengthComputable":"true","loaded":"33040","total":"491176"}
{"bubbles":"false","cancelBubble":"false","cancelable":"false","lengthComputable":"true","loaded":"98576","total":"491176"}
{"bubbles":"false","cancelBubble":"false","cancelable":"false","lengthComputable":"true","loaded":"131344","total":"491176"}
{"bubbles":"false","cancelBubble":"false","cancelable":"false","lengthComputable":"true","loaded":"147728","total":"491176"}
{"bubbles":"false","cancelBubble":"false","cancelable":"false","lengthComputable":"true","loaded":"164112","total":"491176"}
{"bubbles":"false","cancelBubble":"false","cancelable":"false","lengthComputable":"true","loaded":"180496","total":"491176"}
{"bubbles":"false","cancelBubble":"false","cancelable":"false","lengthComputable":"true","loaded":"213264","total":"491176"}
{"bubbles":"false","cancelBubble":"false","cancelable":"false","lengthComputable":"true","loaded":"229648","total":"491176"}
{"bubbles":"false","cancelBubble":"false","cancelable":"false","lengthComputable":"true","loaded":"65808","total":"491176"}
{"bubbles":"false","cancelBubble":"false","cancelable":"false","lengthComputable":"true","loaded":"82192","total":"491176"}
{"bubbles":"false","cancelBubble":"false","cancelable":"false","lengthComputable":"true","loaded":"114960","total":"491176"}
{"bubbles":"false","cancelBubble":"false","cancelable":"false","lengthComputable":"true","loaded":"295184","total":"491176"}
{"bubbles":"false","cancelBubble":"false","cancelable":"false","lengthComputable":"true","loaded":"262416","total":"491176"}
{"bubbles":"false","cancelBubble":"false","cancelable":"false","lengthComputable":"true","loaded":"311568","total":"491176"}
{"bubbles":"false","cancelBubble":"false","cancelable":"false","lengthComputable":"true","loaded":"327952","total":"491176"}
{"bubbles":"false","cancelBubble":"false","cancelable":"false","lengthComputable":"true","loaded":"344336","total":"491176"}
{"bubbles":"false","cancelBubble":"false","cancelable":"false","lengthComputable":"true","loaded":"360720","total":"491176"}
{"bubbles":"false","cancelBubble":"false","cancelable":"false","lengthComputable":"true","loaded":"377104","total":"491176"}
{"bubbles":"false","cancelBubble":"false","cancelable":"false","lengthComputable":"true","loaded":"409872","total":"491176"}
{"bubbles":"false","cancelBubble":"false","cancelable":"false","lengthComputable":"true","loaded":"442640","total":"491176"}
{"bubbles":"false","cancelBubble":"false","cancelable":"false","lengthComputable":"true","loaded":"393488","total":"491176"}
{"bubbles":"false","cancelBubble":"false","cancelable":"false","lengthComputable":"true","loaded":"426256","total":"491176"}
{"bubbles":"false","cancelBubble":"false","cancelable":"false","lengthComputable":"true","loaded":"459024","total":"491176"}
{"bubbles":"false","cancelBubble":"false","cancelable":"false","lengthComputable":"true","loaded":"475408","total":"491176"}
{"bubbles":"false","cancelBubble":"false","cancelable":"false","lengthComputable":"true","loaded":"491163","total":"491176"}
{"bubbles":"false","cancelBubble":"false","cancelable":"false","lengthComputable":"true","loaded":"196880","total":"491176"}
{"bubbles":"false","cancelBubble":"false","cancelable":"false","lengthComputable":"true","loaded":"246032","total":"491176"}
```

what's wrong with the property loaded;why it increase repeatly;

---

**upload code**

```
$scope.upload = function(imageURI) {
    $scope.dangerList[$scope.setting.num][$scope.setting.imageType + '1pic'] = imageURI;
    var server = 'http://localhost/test.php';
    var dirName = 'check';
    var desName = 'test';
    var options = {
        'httpMethod': 'POST',
        'params': {
            'dirName': dirName,
            'desName': desName
        }
    };
    var promise = $cordovaFileTransfer.upload(server, imageURI, options, true);
    promise.then(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    }, function(data) {}, function(evt) {
        $ionicLoading.show({
            template: '<p>upload:' + parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded / evt.total) + '%</p>',
            //duration: 1000,
        });
    });
    return promise;
};
```

**and ngCordova\src\plugins\fileTransfer.js**

```
angular.module('ngCordova.plugins.fileTransfer', [])

.factory('$cordovaFileTransfer', ['$q', '$timeout', function($q, $timeout) {
    return {
        download: function(source, filePath, options, trustAllHosts) {
            var q = $q.defer();
            var ft = new FileTransfer();
            var uri = (options && options.encodeURI === false) ? source : encodeURI(source);

            if (options && options.timeout !== undefined && options.timeout !== null) {
                $timeout(function() {
                    ft.abort();
                }, options.timeout);
                options.timeout = null;
            }

            ft.onprogress = function(progress) {
                q.notify(progress);
            };

            q.promise.abort = function() {
                ft.abort();
            };

            ft.download(uri, filePath, q.resolve, q.reject, trustAllHosts, options);
            return q.promise;
        },

        upload: function(server, filePath, options, trustAllHosts) {
            var q = $q.defer();
            var ft = new FileTransfer();
            var uri = (options && options.encodeURI === false) ? server : encodeURI(server);

            if (options && options.timeout !== undefined && options.timeout !== null) {
                $timeout(function() {
                    ft.abort();
                }, options.timeout);
                options.timeout = null;
            }

            ft.onprogress = function(progress) {
                q.notify(progress);
            };

            q.promise.abort = function() {
                ft.abort();
            };

            ft.upload(filePath, uri, q.resolve, q.reject, options, trustAllHosts);
            return q.promise;
        }
    };
}]);
```

**and push interceptor**

```
.factory('UserInterceptor', function ($q, $rootScope) {
    return {
        request:function(config){
            config.headers = config.headers || {};
            config.headers.UID = $rootScope.user.id || 0;
            return config;
        },
        requestError: function(err){
            return $q.reject(err);
        },
        response: function (response) {
            return response;
        },
    };
})
```

---

it could work few days ago.
during the time,

1. add plaform with android@5.1.1 instead of android@4.1.1;
2. update cordova;
3. use ionic 1.7.3 now;

---

**and here is the download code,it can works,but will download file twice**

```
$scope.down = function(fname) {
    var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
    var uri = encodeURI($rootScope.rootUrl + fname);
    var fileURL = cordova.file.externalRootDirectory + fname;
    fileTransfer.download(
        uri,
        fileURL,
        function(entry) {
            console.log(entry);
        },
        function(error) {
            console.log(error);
        },
        false, {
            headers: {
                "Authorization": "Basic dGVzdHVzZXJuYW1lOnRlc3RwYXNzd29yZA=="
            }
        }
    );
};
```

Comment: Hi teemo, welcome to StackOverflow. Please clarify your question, I am afraid the current state of it unfortunately won't lead to an answer...

Answer (score 0):

This is actually the response from progress event of cordovaFileTransfer.
On success it'll give response something like this:

```
Object {bytesSent: 3228135, responseCode: 200, response: "<!-- Served from 80.251.0.59 / test.talia.net, as …imited↵</p>↵↵</td></tr></table>↵↵</body>↵</html>↵", objectId: ""}
```

But as per the output you are getting,I think the function is getting interrupted by the same method from another instance because your whole file was almost uploaded in the 3rd last line.

```
"cancelable":"false","lengthComputable":"true","loaded":"491163","total":"491176"}
```

And then it picked up from some another point.
Please provide the code so I can try to assist you further.
Thank you

Comment: i added some code just now @PRANSHU MIDHA,and thanks for help

Comment: **RESOLVED**: 
Downgrade the plugin cordova-plugin-file-transfer from 1.6.3 to 1.5.0, and then it works.